# Return a mocked object from a mocked object in Google mock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I have the following setup:

```
class MockObject : public Parent
{
public:
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD0( GetSecondMockedObject, const Parent&() );
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD0( SomethingReturnsBool, const bool() );
};
```

I have

```
MockObject mockParentObj;
MockObject mockChildObj;

// I create the following expectation on mockChildObj
EXPECT_CALL( mockChildObj, SomethingReturnsBool() ).WillRepeatedly( Return( true ) );

// I create the following expectation on mockParentObj
EXPECT_CALL( mockParentObject, GetSecondMockedObject() ).WillRepeatedly( ReturnRef( mockChildObj ) );



// I am going to use the parent mock object somewhere
realProductionObject.SomeRealFunction( mockParentObject );

// Definition of SomeRealFunction is part of the production code
SomeRealFunction( Parent& pObject )
{
    // Method #1

    // This should call the parent mock object which should return the child
    // mock object. Then on that object I call SomethingReturnsBool()
    // and the value of "val" should be true.
    const Parent& childObject = pObject.GetSecondMockedObject().
    bool val = childObject.SomethingReturnsBool();

    // Method #2

    // This also throws an error
    // bool val = pObject.GetSecondMockedObject().SomethingReturnsBool();
}
```

However, when I execute the code( which is a bit different than this code and it compiles without an issue) I get the following exception and it is caused by the call to SomethingReturnsBool():

```
First-chance exception at 0x023CC193 in MyTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCE8.
Critical error detected c0000374
```

I am suspecting that the child mock object reference returned from the call GetSecondMockObject() is invalid. I am not sure how else to pass it? I tried using:
`ReturnPointee( &... )` instead of `ReturnRef( ... )` but that also didn't work.

I would appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Try passing `mockParentObject` by reference to `SomeRealFunction`, not by value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @RA. However, that doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: Also, you need to ensure that the `childObject` in `SomeRealFunction` is of type `const Parent&`, not `Parent`.

Comment: I just updated the question with the things I've tried.

Comment: Your code above still doesn't show that `SomeRealFunction` takes in a `Parent` by reference.  If that doesn't fix it, then the problem must be elsewhere -- I can't reproduce your problem otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Your SomeRealFunction(Parent pObject) you need to pass a reference or pointer because you lost your mock configuration on copy object.

My code follow run without problems:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <assert.h>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace testing;

class Parent
{
public:
    virtual ~Parent() {}
    Parent() {}

    virtual const Parent& GetSecondMockedObject() const { return *this; }
    virtual const bool SomethingReturnsBool() const { return false; }
};

class MockObject : public Parent
{
public:
  MOCK_CONST_METHOD0( GetSecondMockedObject, const Parent&() );
  MOCK_CONST_METHOD0( SomethingReturnsBool, const bool() );
};


class MyRealObject
{
public:

// Definition of SomeRealFunction is part of the production code
void SomeRealFunction(const Parent& pObject )
{
    std::cout << "parent = " << &pObject << std::endl;
    const Parent& childObject = pObject.GetSecondMockedObject();
    std::cout << "child = " << &childObject << std::endl;
    bool val = childObject.SomethingReturnsBool();
    std::cout << "val = " << val << std::endl;
}
};

TEST(mytest, tehet)
{
  MockObject mockParentObj;
  MockObject mockChildObj;

  EXPECT_CALL(mockChildObj, SomethingReturnsBool() ).WillRepeatedly( Return( true ) );
  EXPECT_CALL(Const(mockParentObj), GetSecondMockedObject() ).WillRepeatedly( ReturnRef( mockChildObj ) );

  MyRealObject myobj;
  myobj.SomeRealFunction(mockParentObj);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc,argv);

  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```